# cakephp - Form fields getting pre-filled with '1'

Tags: cakephp-4.x

I have an associative array of fields in my view like :

```
$fields = ['field1' => '1', 'field2' => '0', 'field3' => '1']
```

This array comes from a checklist of fields on another page. '1' means that the field was selected and '0' means that it wasn't(and shouldn't be displayed).

I am creating a form using this array as :

```
foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
                if ($value == 1) {
                    echo $this->Form->control($key, ['class' => 'form-control w-80 mb-3 ml-3', 'label' => ['class' => 'ml-3', 'text' => $key], 'type' => 'text']);
                }
            }
```

The fields are getting filled with 1 on their own. I would like them to be blank. Can anyone please help me with this?
Thankyou.

Comment: Do these fields have default values set in the database schema? Have you tried adding `'default' => false` to the [options passed to the `control` function](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views/helpers/form.html#common-options-for-specific-controls)?

Comment: Even if these fields have a default value, it can't be 1. Also, I tried using the `'default' => false` option but it's still the same :(

Comment: Okay I added `'value' => ''` and it works!